# Scaling an image to disappear from left to right

Tags: iphone, animation, transform, scale, uianimation

I have an image that I would like to make disappear by scaling the image to 0.0 horizontal from left to right.

First I tried this code, which makes the image grow very large and twirl around the screen before disappearing:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
imageName.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.0, 1.0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Then I changed the transformation to scale(0.1, 1.0)

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:0.6];
imageName.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeScale(0.1, 1.0);
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

This creates exactly the effect that I want, except that it shrinks to 0.1 horizontal scale from both the left and right sides, meeting in the middle. I want it to shrink from left to right, and I also want it to shrink all the way to 0.0 so that it is completely invisible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want it to shrink from left to right

Set `imageName.layer.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(1.0f, 0.5f);` before you start the animation.

> and I also want it to shrink all the way to 0.0 so that it is completely invisible.

Try setting a scale factor that is very small but not zero, such as `0.000001`. Then, when the animation is finished, remove the view from its superview.

Comment: Thanks! This works great to create the animation I wanted BUT it moves the image to the left when that anchorPoint is set. I can fudge it by having the image start off further to the right than I want in IB and setting the anchorPoint during viewDidLoad so it pops left to the right spot, but it'd be nice to know if I can avoid the anchorPoint moving the image if you have any ideas.  Thanks again!

Comment: Here is what I did:


CGRect frame = imageName.frame;
imageName.layer.position = CGPointMake((imageName.layer.position.x + ((frame.size.width / 2)), imageName.layer.position.y);

This moved the image back to the right to compensate for the movement to the left that happened when I set the anchorPoint at (1.0f, 0.5f)